# How can I store more information in a session in Zend?

Tags: zend-framework

So I created a user system, and I want to grab the a few other fields from my database after `authenticate()`ing them. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store extra information in the identity beyond the typical, you can do something like this upon successful authentication.

This is in my login controller, `processAction()` upon successful authentication:

```
$identity = new stdClass;
$identity->username = strtolower( $auth->getIdentity() );
$identity->miscParam1 = 'Miscellaneous parameter1';
$identity->miscParam2 = 'Miscellaneous parameter2';
# ... etc ...

$storage = $auth->getStorage();
$storage->write($identity);
```

It's important to note that if you use this approach, then every time you want to get the username or the other parameters, you will need to retrieve it like so:

```
$identity = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->read();
echo $identity->username; # echo is just for example
echo $identity->miscParam1;
echo $identity->miscParam2;
```

Note that you would use `getStorage()->read()` instead of `getIdentity()` (which might also work but I am not sure).

Now, the only thing left to do is populate `$identity->miscParam1` (etc) with information from your database using Zend_Db_Select. (Looking back at your question... I hope you weren't asking how to query. I probably didn't even answer your question.)

Comment: `Zend_Auth->getIdentity()` calls `Zend_Auth->getStorage()->read()` except it returns null if the storage is empty, so using getIdentity is fine since its a bit shorter, and maybe more descriptive of what is happening.

Comment: @drew010 That's good to know. I'll start using that myself. :)